# Minecraft will not work after Windows 10 installation. Launcher claims game crashed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, windows-10

Ever since my grandma installed Windows 10 on her computer (the one I want to fix Minecraft on), Minecraft won't go past the launcher screen. I have tried **many** things such as:

- Uninstalling and Re-installing
- Deleting the contents of my .minecraft folder
- Many other things.

It has been going on ever since about 1.10, and my grandmas computer expert claims that Minecraft isn't compatible with Windows 10 (Which I know is an absolute lie, because with every other computer my dad has installed Windows 10 and Minecraft on they both are perfectly fine together). I have a hard time believing it's the computer itself, because that seems ridiculous. I'm curious as to whether anyone knows: A solution to this, things that might have been installed with it that are not compatible with Minecraft, if something is wrong with my Minecraft, or simply if you just have any ideas that are completely obvious that I've not thought of in the past 2 years.

If you need any more info on this, just tell me and I'll try to do my best to deliver that to you.

Comment: Are you installing the older Java version of Minecraft or the newer non-Java one?

Comment: What exactly happens? Does it crash? Does it show an error message? Does it just completely ignore your mouse click? Does it start and then close? What's the last thing that works correctly?

Comment: I open my launcher, I click play, it loads and closes the launcher, and then after a couple of seconds it re-opens the launcher with a gray box with text that says

                                                **GAME CRASH**

An unexpected issue occurred and the game has crashed. We're sorry for the inconvenience. 

And then below it there's a big green button with "CLOSE" on it, won't let me right click on it or anything.

Comment: Also, I've been downloading the one from this website.

https://minecraft.net/en-us/download/

Comment: @Mel Do you know what version you are trying to install? The latest is 1.12.2. Additionally, depending on the version, what version of Java do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Delete your .minecraft folder. (Remember to back up world files to cloud, if possible.) Then, download Minecraft with the **old launcher** from here: https://minecraft.net/en-us/download/alternative.

Comment: I did so, and it did the same, but instead of 'An unexpected issue occurred and the game has crashed' it says 'Uhoh, it looks like the game has crashed! Sorry for the inconvenience :('

Comment: Try updating your Java runtime environment. Go to oracle's website and download a Java update.

Answer (score 0):

If you've re-installed and are still having the same issue it sounds like an issue with java, possibly try to update java.

Answer (score -1):

There is a windows 10 version of minecraft and the java version for windows versions before Windows 10.  You want to make certain you are installing the correct version.  When I bought my game, I was given a license for both.  I believe the Windows 10 version is downloaded from the Microsoft store.  So your grandmother's computer guy was half right.  You need the correct version of minecraft for Windows 10.

Otherwise, there could easily be a problem with the computer.  I work part-time running a little computer repair business, and I can tell you from experience that the vast majority of people have computers loaded with junk software that can create all sorts of problems.  Typically, it's the software that came with the computer that is the biggest culprit.

One of the first things I do when I set up new computers is to remove almost all of the software that was installed on it.  Very little of it is of any value.  Then I install the software that the person actually needs.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install a version of java 8 not higher than 51 in build.